# Autosizing image based on figcomment size?

Tags: html, css

hoping someone can point me in the right direction. I have a simple grid photo gallery (images are mismatched sizes and aspect ratios).

I'm trying to figure out how to size the height of the <img> so that it leaves enough room for the <figcomment> (which varies in height based on the number of tags).

- If I set <img> to 'height: 100%;', <figcomment> overflows the <figure>.
- If I set 'height: auto;', landscape images leave too much space above the <figcomment>.

Is there a way to correctly size the <img> so that it fills the <figure> without pushing the <figcomment> outside?

Putting the <figcomment> above the <img> and setting <figure> 'overflow: hidden' does what I want, but I would prefer to have the tags underneath the image?

```html
<figure>
  <a href="/photo/349">
    <img src="/images/77.jpeg">
  </a>
  <figcaption>
    <a href="/tag/dog">dog</a>
  </figcaption>
</figure>
<figure>
  <a href="/photo/251">
    <img src="/images/104.jpeg">
  </a>
  <figcaption>
    <a href="/tag/tink">tink, </a>
    <a href="/tag/dog">dog, </a>
    <a href="/tag/human">human</a>
  </figcaption>
</figure>
<figure>
  <a href="/photo/361">
    <img src="/images/88.jpeg">
  </a>
  <figcaption>
    <a href="/tag/adam">adam, </a>
    <a href="/tag/dio">dio, </a>
    <a href="/tag/dog">dog, </a>
    <a href="/tag/human">human, </a>
    <a href="/tag/car">car</a>
  </figcaption>
</figure>
```

```css
section {
  display: grid;
  column-gap: var(--colGap);
  row-gap: calc(var(--colGap) * 1.618);
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, var(--photoW));
  justify-content: center;
}
figure {
  width: var(--photoW);
  height: calc(var(--photoW) * 1.618);
  padding: 5px;
  border: 2px solid var(--accent);
  border-bottom-left-radius: 8px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 8px;
}
img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  object-fit: cover;
}
figcaption {
  padding: .3em;
  margin-left: -7px;
  width: var(--photoW);
  color: var(--dark);
  font-size: 18px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the process of writing the above I realised that I could solve the problem by letting the image completely fill the figure and then absolutely positioning the figcomment.

```css
img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
figcaption {
  position: absolute;
  right: 5px;
  bottom: 2px;
}
```

This works, but I'd be interested if there are any more elegant solutions?